# How to explicitly resize frames in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

so i'm currently working on a piece of code that'll be integrating into something else later to act as a settings configurator. For the time being, i want to have a window that is laid out like you see below:
[image: Layout]

where each coloured box is a frame. This window is **not** resizable and will always be 480x720 pixels. As such, i want the 3 frames im using, sideBar(yellow), container (blue) and static(red) to always remain the same size and fill the window as pictured above with roughly the same ratios (doesn't need to be exact).

The code for this window is below

```
        self.window = tk.Tk()

        self.windowHeight = 480
        self.windowLength = 720
        self.windowDimensions = str(self.windowLength)+"x"+str(self.windowHeight) #make diemnsions string; dimensions are set as a single string
        self.window.geometry(self.windowDimensions)
        self.window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.container = tk.Frame(self.window, relief="sunken", borderwidth=2) #instantiate new window
        self.sideBar = tk.Frame(self.window,  relief="sunken", borderwidth=2)
        self.static = tk.Frame(self.window, relief="sunken", borderwidth=2)

        self.sideBar.grid_propagate(False)
        self.sideBar.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.container.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.static.grid(row=5, column=1)


        self.configuratorObject = configuratorObject 

        audioButton = tk.Button(self.sideBar, text="Audio Page", command=lambda: self.raisePage("audioPage"))
        colourButton = tk.Button(self.sideBar, text="Colours", command=lambda: self.raisePage("coloursPage"))
        saveButton = tk.Button(self.static, text = "Save", state="disabled")
        applyButton = tk.Button(self.static, text = "Apply", state="disabled")
        audioButton.pack()
        colourButton.pack()
        saveButton.pack()
        applyButton.pack()
```

I've attempted to change the `height` and `width` parameters of the grids, but they really don't seem to be doing anything. So how could i go about explicitly defining the layout and sizes of the frames?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why do you want to explicitly set sizes, rather than letting tkinter do all the work of calculating the best fit? Also, why prevent the user from resizing the window?

Comment: @BryanOakley If theres a way of getting tkinter to do it then that'd be great, however i can only seem to get pack() or grid() to make the frames as big as their contents rather than filling the whole window. I'm preventing resizing for ease of use

Comment: Preventing resize is the opposite of ease-of-use. If a user's resolution is different than yours, or their font sizes are different, or their vision is worse than yours, they may not be able to use the window.

Comment: @BryanOakley i understand that, i'm just looking for a solution to my problem atm thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the comments you wrote

> If theres a way of getting tkinter to do it then that'd be great

That is definitely the preferred way, over forcing widgets to be a particular size.

We'll start by using `pack` instead of `grid` for the three frames. For such a basic layout it requires fewer lines of code than `grid`.

```
self.sideBar.pack(side="left", fill="y")
self.static.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Next, add the buttons on the left. This will cause the left frame to shrink in width to fit the buttons. Because we used `fill="y"`, the height will be forced to remain the full height of the window.

```
audioButton.pack(side="top", fill="x")
colourButton.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

Finally, add the buttons on the bottom. Your original code shows them stacked top-to-bottom but your illustration shows them in a single horizontal row. This example adheres to the illustration.

```
applyButton.pack(side="right", padx=10)
saveButton.pack(side="right", padx=10)
```

With that we end up with a window that looks like the following, and the proportions and orientation stays exactly the same when you resize the window:

[image: screenshot]

---

Note: you can do this with `grid` too, but it requires a few more lines of code to apply weights to the rows and columns. I personally prefer `pack` when the layout doesn't naturally fit in a grid since it requires fewer lines of code.

Comment: if i were to want to make the sidebar wider purely for aesthetics, how would i go about doing that? I tried using padx on the buttons, however that leaves a gap between the edge of the button and the frame

Comment: @carbaretta If you want wider buttons, one technique is to simply make wider buttons. Button objects have a `width` attribute. Another solution is to use `pack`'s `ipadx` option, for example `audioButton.pack(side="top", fill="x", ipadx=20)`.